# How to get "only the x-coordinate" of a randomly selected turtle from the turtles that exist in a straight line on the x-axis?

Tags: netlogo

How do I get only the x-coordinate of a randomly selected turtle from the turtles that exist in a straight line on the x-axis and make it a variable?
For example, here's a sample code, but it doesn't work.

```
  globals [x-only]
  ;omitted
  ask one-of turtles with [xcor < max-pxcor and  pycor < 1 and pycor > -1][
   set x-only list xcor ycor  ;I might be wrong here, but there are no good syntax.
   move-to patch x-only 1
  ]
  ;omitted
```

Comment: Do you need x-only?  Can't you just `move-to patch xcor 1`

Comment: Yes, that's right! Thank you. Please feel free to post it here as an answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't really know netlogo, but if you really did want to store xcor in a global x-only variable then the assignment would be `set x-only int xcor`, wouldn't it?